# Images not showing in Magento Website

Tags: css, image, magento

I am new to coding and I am having issues with my sister's website. I have uploaded a 'add to bag' and 'wishlist' button to the products page http://v4vintage.com/magento/index.php/vintage-jewellery/bracelets-bangles/1970s-abstract-green-quartz-bracelet.html and it is not showing in Firefox and corrupted in other browsers. Why is wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your image and not in your 'coding' (CSS or HTML). The image is corrupted already when you export it: http://v4vintage.com/magento/skin/frontend/vintage/default/images/wishlist.gif.

You should export it as PNG if you want to use it as a background in your button and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Agis, many thanks.  I have created a new file and exported it as a PNG and I have the same problem.

Comment: Can you post the link to your image? Without some evidence it's hard to tell. Which program do you use to create your graphics?

Comment: I have just created a black box in Fireworks (121 px x 24px) for now to see if it will work, then I was going to recreate the button.

Comment: The URL is http://v4vintage.com/magento/skin/frontend/vintage/default/images/wishlist.png.  I have looked and it said there is an error.

Comment: It has worked thank you!  I was using fire ftp and it was corrupting my files when transferring to the ftp site.  I uploaded files directing via the hosting site and it is fine.

Comment: If this answer was helpful please mark it as accepted and upvote it, so others can benefit from it. Thanks =)